# Possible to create mailing group from multiple email addresses in a message I received?

Tags: gmail, outlook.com

Say I get an email with 30 addresses in the `To:` field (or `CC`, etc) is it possible to create a new mailing group from all these people in any webmail app?

I'm sort of primarily looking for this in Hotmail and Gmail, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a way to do this directly.

This is the fastest way I found to do it in Gmail.

1. Click "show details" to display the entire To: field
2. Copy all of the e-mail addresses shown there
3. Change to "Contacts" and select "New Group"
4. Click on the group name to display it
5. Click the button which says `Add to "<groupname>"`. This will open a simple text area
6. Paste the e-mail addresses you copied into the text area

If any of the e-mail addresses are already in your contacts they'll just be added to the group.

It certainly does seem like Google is missing an opportunity here, though.

Comment: Thanks Al, that does indeed seem to be the best that I can do. I'm going to continue leaving the question open in case one day some webmail/email provider actually adds this feature.